# Chrome extension, chrome extension communication

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Below is my manifest.json:
{

```
 "name": "My Extension Name",

 "version": "1.9.1",

 "manifest_version": 2,

 "icons": {  "16": "icon16.png",

             "48": "icon48.png",

             "128": "icon128.png" },

 "homepage_url": "https://www.mysite.com",

 "description": "My Extension Description",

 "permissions": ["http://www.example.com/*"],

 "content_scripts" : [{

         "matches" : [ "http://www.example.com/*"],

         "js" : ["contentscript.js"],

         "run_at" : "document_end"

  }],

        "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"]
```

}

My contentscript.js is:

var s = document.createElement('script');

s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");

(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

script.js:

$.post("https://www.mysite.com/app/myfolder/", function(html){

```
  $("body").prepend(html);
```

});

I would like to access the DOM in http://www.example.com/. There is a form in http://www.example.com/. when the submit button of the form is clicked, iw ould like to get the post values in www.mysite.com. How to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can intercept, process, and tamper with a site's `POST` data using the `chrome.webRequest` interface. Just implement `webRequest` in your `manifest.json` and add an `onBeforeSendHeaders` function in your content-script. More documentation can be found on the [Google Chrome Extension Developers Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

Comment: Content scripts have access to only a [limited number of Chrome extension APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). `chrome.webRequest` is not one that content scripts have access to. Anything to do with `chrome.webRequest` will have to be done in a background script.