# Listen to click event in web page chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, code-injection

Am developing a chrome extension. Am injecting a script in a wbpage using contentscript as follows:

```
  var s = document.createElement('script');

   s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");

   (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

My script.js:

```
$.post("https://www.example.com/srv/example/", function(html){


    $("body").prepend(html);


 });
```

Now, i would like to listen to a button click event in the webpage DOM ? How to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can listen with

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', yourListenerFunction, true);
```

BTW, you're executing your content script in a very odd way.  The usual is using some code in your background.js, like:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file:"yourScriptFile.js"});
```

I recommend this https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview

Comment: But i haven't used any background.js. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792627/chrome-extension-chrome-extension-communication for my manifest.json

Comment: Ok, you have your reasons to insert the script.js on the html document.  You can still listen to click event like I posted.  It work on the extension's content script as well as on the html document.